# GLEW functions "could not be resolved"?

Tags: opengl, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use OpenGL to create a game engine. However I'm having trouble with my shaders. I'm trying to use functions such as glCreateProgram() and glUseProgram() and eclipse shows me the little "YOU'RE ABOUT TO BREAK EVERYTHING" beetle on the code line saying that "Function (gl function) could not be resolved" I'm not sure if this is a false positive with Eclipse because I've linked GLEW and I don't get a compiler error.

Shader.cpp

```
#include "shader.h"

Shader::Shader() {
    program = glCreateProgram();
}

Shader::~Shader() {

}
```

shader.h

```
#define SHADER_H_

#include <GL/glew.h>

class Shader {

    public:
        Shader();
        virtual ~Shader();

    private:

        GLuint program;

};

#endif /* SHADER_H_ */
```

And my build report

```
16:50:29 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project SDL_OpenGL_Project ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Shader.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Shader.d" -MT"src/Shader.d" -o     "src/Shader.o" "../src/Shader.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Shader.cpp

Building target: SDL_OpenGL_Project
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "SDL_OpenGL_Project"  ./src/Display.o ./src/InputHandler.o ./src/Shader.o
./src/main.o   -lSDL2 -lGLEW -lGL
Finished building target: SDL_OpenGL_Project


16:50:30 Build Finished (took 928ms)
```

I've taken out some of the unfinished code that isn't relevant to the question. And I do invoke an instance of this class in my main method in a separate class. I'm a little new so I'm unsure of this problem, since I've linked glew and gl.

Comment: Are you referring to an IDE feature here? You have to realize that what GLEW does is resolve these functions at ***run-time*** by communicating with the driver. As far as the IDE is concerned, those functions are just pointers and that can be confusing... it's an issue of static analysis vs. dynamic run-time behavior.

Comment: So any time I use these functions eclipse will say they don't exist because they don't until the program is run?

Comment: More or less. I believe it is because they are implemented as pre-processor macros in GLEW and the IDE probably doesn't evaluate them. You'll see this problem in pretty much any IDE including Visual Studio. You have something along the lines of: `#define  glCreateShader   GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewCreateShader)`

Comment: But that's all that glew.h does though, is there a way to fix this in all instaces? I'm kinda confused because that code line is right in glew.h

Comment: @LoreleiRS: Eventually the functions have to be resolved dynamically at some time. And because functions starting with `gl…` belong to the OpenGL namespace, which other libraries must not use, but GLEW *is* *another* library, it must do this preprocessor trickery so that the programmer sees literals in the nice `gl…` namespace, although technically they're just preprocessor literals. If it really means that much to it, you could use some preprocessor trickery to detect IDE parsing runs and to dispatch to either `glew.h` or `glext.h` with prototypes enabled, depending on what's parsing it.